# problemas con flutter

Tags: linux, flutter, vscode

Buen día, tengo un problema al compilar con flutter desde linux (nobara linux) usando vscode, obtengo esto:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
main.dart:1
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_PRIVATE' not found (required by /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1) (search paths :/usr/lib/dri:/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
** (flutter_application_1:10541): WARNING **: 10:02:20.014: Failed to start Flutter renderer: No se pudo crear un contexto GL
```

ya agregue flutter al path, ya puse la linea para que use las librerías de flutter, instale las dependencias que piden y ya no se que hacer, ya trate de ejecutarlo en linux, con emulador y ninguno carga, lamento si es una tontería pero apenas inicio, lo siento.

Answer (score 1):

No suena a una tontería. De hecho, parece que es [algo](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=56273) que afecta [a muchos usuarios](https://superuser.com/questions/695544/issues-with-libgl-on-fedora-20-unable-to-load-driver-swrast) en diferentes escenarios y [sistemas operativos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412683/ubuntu-20-04-libgl-error-failed-to-load-driver-swrast).

Entiendo que swrast viene con los MESA drivers e incluso hay [algún bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1121372) relacionado y registrado en Fedora.

Habría que ver si con las soluciones que plantean en esas preguntas e hilos, puedes resolver tu problema.

- Instalar `mesa-dri-drivers.x86_64`, `mesa-utils`, `libgl1-mesa-glx`.
- Instalar drivers de video diferentes a los que están en el repo de tu distro, que pueden no ser los más recientes (para nvidia sería algo [así](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-fedora-linux/))
- Al arrancar en el GRUB, modificar el arranque de nobara y añadirle `i915.modeset=1` al arranque del OS.

Comment: muchas gracias, lo intentare , igual no se me hubiera imaginado lo del grub,muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: @BrayanmaldonadoPerera déjanos saber si lo logras! Lamento no ser de más ayuda

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje:

> Failed to start Flutter renderer: No se pudo crear un contexto GL

Indica que `Flutter` no puede iniciar, debido a un problema con la creación de un contexto de gráficos en `Flutter`, debido a problemas de configuración o incompatibilidad con la GPU. Es muy importante que inicies por revisar que cuentas con los requisitos mínimos para usar `Flutter` en Linux.

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux

```
Operating Systems: Linux (64-bit)
Disk Space: 600 MB (does not include disk space for IDE/tools).
Tools: Flutter depends on these command-line tools being available in your environment.
bash
curl
file
git 2.x
mkdir
rm
unzip
which
xz-utils
zip
Shared libraries: Flutter test command depends on this library being available in your environment.
libGLU.so.1 - provided by mesa packages such as libglu1-mesa on Ubuntu/Debian and mesa-libGLU on Fedora.
```

puesto que precisamente esto es lo que indica la documentación:

> Bibliotecas compartidas: el comando `test` de Flutter depende de
> que esta biblioteca esté disponible en su entorno. `libGLU.so.1`:
> proporcionado por paquetes mesa como `libglu1-mesa` en Ubuntu/Debian y
> `mesa-libGLU` en Fedora.

Te sugiero usar "Flutter doctor", revisará tu configuración y realizará los cambios necesarios para que funcione Flutter:

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#run-flutter-doctor

Comment: gracias, tenog isntaladas todas esas librerias que marca la paqueteria segun yo,pero revisare de nuevo por cualquier cosa, muchas gracias

Comment: @BrayanmaldonadoPerera usa Flutter doctor por favor y comenta que te indica